# Why is /var/www/html writable only by root (by default)?

Tags: debian, permissions, apache-httpd, web

After setting up LAMP (on Debian) and then looking at /var/www/html's permissions, I was surprised that it is only writeable by root (`drwxr-xr-x 1 root root`).

Presumably PHP scripts can create files in /var/www/html, but surely a PHP script (or it's interpreter) doesn't run in the name of root? Can anyone help me understand whatever I am misunderstanding?

EDIT:

I installed PHP with `apt-get install php5-common libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-cli`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP scripts will run as either:

- The user running Apache as determined by the `User` directive in your Apache configuration (usually `apache` or `nobody`) if you are using `mod_php`
- The user running PHP-FPM if you are using `php-fpm`

So the user a PHP script will execute as will vary.  So it's up to you to set the owner and group of `/var/www/html` (or wherever your `DocumentRoot` is) accordingly.

Furthermore, you may not wish for your PHP application to be able to write (or overwrite) files in your `DocumentRoot` at all, as this could allow a visitor to a compromised or insecure PHP web application to gain remote code execution privileges.  So it's your responsibility to decide whether or not your PHP application is trustworthy enough to allow it to write to files that Apache can serve over the web or even execute.

PHP will almost never (and should never!) be run as root for similar reasons to those mentioned above.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I should never `service apache2 restart` as root?

Comment: That should be posted as a separate question, but I can answer that quickly here. `sudo service apache2 restart` does **not** cause Apache to be run as the root user.  The user that Apache runs as is determined by the `User` directive in the Apache configs.

Answer (score 1):

Centos/RHEL already used root:root for /var/www/html.It's about security issue. apache or nobody was unsecure.Not easy to hack /var/www/html when it set root:root.Debian was late to use root:root on /var/www/html.